# Solving for function f and constant c using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The question says:

[image]

I started by differentiating which gets rid of the constant c, and leaves:

d/dx (∫ f(t)sin(t) = -2cos(x)sin(x).

Assuming this is the right way to start, I'm not sure how to continue.
Do I use the fact that the derivative of the integral of sin(t) is -sin(t) which corresponds to -sin(x) on the right hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, taking the derivative on both sides leads to
$$f(x)\sin(x) = -2\cos(x) \sin(x) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad f(x) = -2\cos(x), $$
for every $x \in \mathbb R$. Substituting this $f$ into the integral leads to
\begin{align}
c + \int_0^{x} -2\cos(t) \sin(t) dt &= \cos^2(x)\\
c + \int_0^{x} -\sin(2t) dt&= \cos^2(x)\\
c + \left[\frac{\cos 2t}{2}\right]_0^x&= \cos^2(x)\\
c + \left[\cos^2(t) - \frac{1}{2}\right]_0^x&= \cos^2(x)\\
c -1 &= 0.
\end{align}

Comment: in your second to last line how did you obtain cos^2(t) on the left hand side?

Comment: This comes from the identity $\cos 2t = 2\cos^2t - 1$